# Windows 10 PC crashes following Kernel-Power Event ID 125

Tags: windows-10, crash, temperature

Every now and then (perhaps once a day) my PC running Windows 10 randomly crashes to a black screen. When this happens, the CPU fan ramps up to full speed until I manually reboot. This doesn't seem to be connected to what the machine is being used for - it's happened running games, but also idle on the desktop. Event Viewer shows the cause is always a Kernel-Power Event ID 125, like this:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
   <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" />
      <EventID>125</EventID>
      <Version>4</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>86</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000020</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-08-30T18:06:09.7493189Z" />
      <EventRecordID>26724</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation />
      <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="404" />
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>DESKTOP-9UFBQA3</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
   </System>
   <EventData>
      <Data Name="ThermalZoneDeviceInstanceLength">9</Data>
      <Data Name="ThermalZoneDeviceInstance">\_TZ.TZ10</Data>
      <Data Name="_PSV">290</Data>
      <Data Name="_TC1">0</Data>
      <Data Name="_TC2">0</Data>
      <Data Name="_TSP">1000</Data>
      <Data Name="_AC0">0</Data>
      <Data Name="_AC1">0</Data>
      <Data Name="_AC2">0</Data>
      <Data Name="_AC3">0</Data>
      <Data Name="_AC4">0</Data>
      <Data Name="_AC5">0</Data>
      <Data Name="_AC6">0</Data>
      <Data Name="_AC7">0</Data>
      <Data Name="_AC8">0</Data>
      <Data Name="_AC9">0</Data>
      <Data Name="_CRT">294</Data>
      <Data Name="_HOT">293</Data>
      <Data Name="MinimumThrottle">0</Data>
      <Data Name="_CR3">0</Data>
      <Data Name="OverThrottleThreshold">0</Data>
      <Data Name="DescriptionLength">0</Data>
      <Data Name="Description" />
      <Data Name="_TZP">10</Data>
   </EventData>
</Event>
```

To me, this looks like the critical temperature was suddenly set to 294K (21°C) so the system failed, because it was obviously hotter than that. But perhaps I'm reading it wrong.

Because I thought it was a temperature issue I have resat my CPU and reapplied thermal paste. I've checked its running temperatures which tend to be in the 30-50°C range. I've made sure all drivers and software are up to date. Now I'm running out of ideas - anyone know what the problem might be? I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: The problem is clearly to do with a temperature sensor, although the reported numbers don't make much sense and no device is indicated. See if you can find more error messages in the Event Viewer. It's possible that some sensor is reporting garbage, or maybe the PSU is having issues. ([useful link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bringup/acpi-defined-devices).) If you have `.dmp` files in `C:\Windows\Minidump` please zip some and post online.  (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Note that the article [The Kernel-Power Event Provider](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/api/po/diag/kernel-power.htm) lists this event as "Event 89" whose description is "ACPI thermal zone ThermalZoneDeviceInstance has been enumerated", so this event might be informative and not really related to the crash (meaning a symptom rather than the cause). The `\_TZ.TZ10` device path refers to Thermal Zone, which is one of the temperature monitoring zones on the motherboard. Check your manual.

Comment: Last: Have you check for a BIOS update? What are your computer and motherboard models?

Comment: @harrymc Unfortunately `C:\Windows\Minidump` is empty, despite it being set to write debugging information is system properties. I'll leave it running overnight, see if it fails again and post a `.dmp` if I can get one.

The motherboard is a Gigabyte Z390 UD and my BIOS is American Megatrends Inc. F9, 15/10/19. Can't see anything about thermal zones in the manual (https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_z390-ud_v2_e.pdf).

Comment: There is a new [BIOS version F10k](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/Z390-UD-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios) from 2021/01/19. You could also email Gigabyte Support and ask what is `_TZ.TZ10` (and any other help they can give). It's possible to see the placement of the [six thermal sensors](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/Z390-UD-rev-10#kf) on the motherboard, but not their ids.